# How to make react router inside of another router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on a project with react-router.

This is a project structure

```
main
   - mainRouter.tsx

   - programFolder
     - ProgramMainComponent.tsx
     - ProgramScheduleComponent.tsx
     - ProgramDetailComponent.tsx
     - programRouter.tsx

   - serviceFolder
     - ServiceMainComponent.tsx
     - ServiceFAQComponent.tsx
     - ServiceCustomerComponent.tsx
     - serviceRouter.tsx
```

And this is how I make programRouter.tsx and serviceRouter.tsx

```
// programRouter.tsx

const ProgramRouter = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
          <Route path={'/program'} exact={true} component={ProgramMainComponent} />
          <Route path={'/program/schedule'}  exact={true} component={ProgramScheduleComponent} />
          <Route path={'/program/detail'}  exact={true} component={ProgramDetailComponent} /
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

// serviceRouter.tsx

const ServiceRouter = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
          <Route path={'/service'} exact={true} component={ServiceMainComponent} />
          <Route path={'/service/faq'}  exact={true} component={ServiceFAQComponent} />
          <Route path={'/program/customer'}  exact={true} component={ServiceCustomerComponent} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Here is the what I want to do.

**As I add more pages, I want have each folder contains each their own router.tsx file and import those files inside of mainRouter.tsx file like the example below.**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { programRouter } from 'main/program';
import { serviceRouter } from 'main/service';

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact={true} component={MainComponent} />
          <Route path={'/program'} exact={true} component={programRouter} />
          <Route path={'/service'} exact={true} component={serviceRouter} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

Is there a way I can use each router components inside fo mainRouter.tsx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of nesting components and routes in the [React Router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting). Basically, you don't need to use `BrowserRouter` more than once at the root level. You should also remove the `exact={true}` props for the routes in the root component to ensure their child routes can render properly.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { programRouter } from 'main/program';
import { serviceRouter } from 'main/service';

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={MainComponent} />
          <Route path={'/program'} component={programRouter} />
          <Route path={'/service'} component={serviceRouter} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```